# c#, Find if String has image links and replace them with html hyperlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I'd like to take a string of text and find out if there is link to image and replace it with html hyperlink, so it looks embedded.

For example:

```html
Look at this image www.xyz/abcd.jpg
```

When I want to display it, then I want to embed the image:

```html
look at this image <img src="www.xyz/abcd.jpg" alt="" />
```

Something like this.

Comment: The problem is that people will not only write "Look at this image"... they could say "LOL have a look:" or something else. And you can't transform every text that contains an image in a hyperlink...

Comment: I changed the formatting because I believe you want to insert HTML. If not, you can use the "rollback" feature to restore your question.

Comment: You look for a regular expression....

Comment: This question is too vague to answer.  My first thought is RegEx.  The pattern could be practically anything.  Voting to close.

Comment: thanks, i was trying to do that and meantime you did it for me, thanks a lot

Comment: @Zarathos - Stackvoerflow converts link text to hyperlinks. Doesn't seem that different to me.

Comment: is jpg the only extension you expect?

Comment: in javascript? or .net codebehind?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey its a new user, maybe to give him a help and stay on SO.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - ASP.NET, C#. Take some input, replace image URLs (ending in .png, .jpg, etc) with a link. Stackoverflow does it. Don't understand your problem with the question.

Comment: Let me try to explain it little more. We have comment section on our website and user can leave comments. If they copy paste the link to image from other site with comments, i want to embed that image. Instead of just showing the link, i want to embed the image with the comments. For example if they paste www.somesite/images/xyz.jpg, then i want to replace that with html img tags, so it looks embedded with the comments. sorry if it was vague earlier on.

Comment: @RajeshGupta Try to not change your question - the answers are all OK and can help you to move one even if you have something a little different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something simple like this:

```
string l_input = "Look at this image www.xyz/abcd.jpg";

l_input = Regex.Replace( 
    l_input, 
    @"(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?(?<=jpg|png|gif)", 
    "<img src=\"$0\" alt=\"\">", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);

// l_input = Look at this image <img src="www.xyz/abcd.jpg" alt="">
```

URL pattern comes from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/

Comment: Updated to ignore case. I imagine you'll want to match some uppercase letters too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like the following:

```
var str = "Look at this image www.xyz/abcd.jpg Look at this image http://www.xyz/abcd.jpg";
var words = str.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    var word = words[i];
    if((word.EndsWith(".png") || word.EndsWith(".jpg")) && 
       (word.StartsWith("http://") || word.StartsWith("www.")))
        words[i] = "<img src=\"" + word + "\" alt=\"\" />";
}
var str2 = String.Join(" ", words);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to do it reliably, but you can try something like this:

```
var str = "quick.brown/fox.jpg http://jumps.over.the/lazy/dog.png";
var link = Regex.Replace(
    str,
    "\\b((?:(?:http|https)://)?[a-zA-Z./]+[.](?:jpg|png))\\b",
    "<img src =\"$1\"/>");
Console.WriteLine(link);
```

The above regex matches anything that ends in `.png` or `.jpg`, and uses a *capturing group* in the `Replace` to surround it with the `src="..."` markup.

Here is a quick [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/e9SnBW). The output looks like this:

```
<img src ="quick.brown/fox.jpg"/> <img src ="http://jumps.over.the/lazy/dog.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
Regex.Replace(url, @"(https?:?//?[^'<>]+?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))", "<img src=\"$0\" alt=\"\">");
```